# ¿How could i get an tribute's value from an input element with Vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Long time ago, this code worked with standard JS / HTML under IE, but now this function is returning "undefined". Why this isn't working? Last time I checked the code, whas with IE60, I know, 10 years ago. So I'm guessing it has relation with the new browsers / html5. Which is the best practice to access an atribute inside an HTML element (In this case, an input) to get it's value and pass it trough the function?

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <input type="button" tipo="MA" onclick="alert(this.tipo);">
 </body>
</html>
```

SOLUTION:

Like some have commented, I have to get use to HTML5. So what I was trying to commit, i got it with:

```html
<input type="button" data-tipo="MA" onclick="alert(this.dataset.tipo);">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `this` supposed to be?

Comment: Because you didn't define property of HTMLInputElement `tipo`?

Comment: Also, you forgot the closing tags

Comment: `alert(this.getAttribute('tipo'));`

Comment: You probably want to avoid creating your own attributes that are not data attributes.  i.e. `<foo ... tipo="MA">` is not supported, but `<foo ... data-tipo="MA">` is.  Bonus with using data elements is, you can then do things like this: `alert(document.getElementById('foo').dataset.tipo)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because with `this.tipo` you are reading a *property* of the HTMLInputElement, not an *attribute*. Those are different things.

If you want attribute use

```
this.getAttribute('tipo')
```

Attributes serve different purposes and usually don'n translate to the property with the same name. Some attributes however do map to corresponding attributes. Examples could be `value`, `disabled`.

Here is a demonstration of how property would work if you did *set* it before reading:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.tipo = 'I am a property'
```

```html
<input type="button" tipo="MA" onclick="alert(this.tipo);">
```

Comment: That worked dfsk! But I have another question, I remember accessing those elements like "this.tipo" and it worked. It has changed something or where can I read some info about that?

Answer (score 2):

Ruben

if you dont want to define a global variable and stick to the inline js you could do something like that:

```
onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('tipo'))
```

The getAttribute() function return the attribute with a specific name.

Also it is quite common now to use the data-* attribute, where the "*" can be replaced by what ever name you want:

```
<element data-name="Ruben">
```

To check more about this I'd advise you to read this: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: Use of `onclick` in HTML is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <html>
   <body>
     <input type="button" value="MA" onclick="alert(this.value);">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: OP wants to get the `tipo` attribute not the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
<html>
 <body>
 <input type="button" tipo="MA" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('tipo'));">
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because JavaScript doesn't speak your language, only some kind of English.
Try this:

```
<html>
 <body>
    <input type="button" tipo="MA" onclick="alert(this.type);">
 </body>
</html>
```